# In app purchases of real goods

Tags: iphone, in-app-purchase

Im wondering if anyone knows a good solution to the problem of selling real goods through an iPhone app?

Is it possible to do with GlobalCollect? And does Apple approve of this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use PayPal to sell Real goods through the iPhone App.

Cheers

Comment: Great. Do you know how to do this?

Comment: Use PayPal's Framework provided for iPhone https://www.x.com/community/ppx/sdks...

Comment: Does apply approve use of this solution?

Answer (score 1):

To the best of my knowledge, Apple strictly forbids this. In-app purchase only allows selling virtual goods strictly related to your application. You may sell functionalities to be unlocked, subscriptions to contents etc, but everything needs to be delivered in-app.